# Kernel driver, is pinctrl property always needed when using GPIO overlay?

Tags: linux-device-driver, device-tree

I've asked this question on Unix Stackexchange, but it seems it was a wrong place for this kind of problem. Ad rem:

I'm creating a kernel driver for SPI controlled display, which is meant to be working with Raspberry PI. Besides the three SPI lines, the display has 3 additional control lines: *BUSY*, *RST* and *DC*. In order to has a possibility of controlling these lines, my DTS has to include additional fragment for GPIO.

```
fragment@0 {
    target = <&spi0>;
    __overlay__ {
        #address-cells = <1>;
        #size-cells = <0>;

        status = "okay";

        spidev@0 {
            status = "disabled";
        };

        epd0: epd@0 {
            compatible = "waveshare,epd";
            reg = <0>;

            pinctrl-names = "default";
            pinctrl-0 = <&epd_pins>;

            spi-max-frequency = <1000000>;

            width = <128>;
            height = <296>;

            dc-gpios = <&gpio 16 0>;
            reset-gpios = <&gpio 20 0>;
            busy-gpios = <&gpio 21 0>;

            status = "okay";
        };
    };
};

fragment@1 {
    target = <&gpio>;
    __overlay__ {
        epd_pins: epd_pins {
            brcm,pins = <16 20 21>; /* DC RST BUSY */
            brcm,function = <1 1 0>; /* out out in */
        };
    };
};
```

That DTS works perfectly fine and I didn't expect any troubles. But there is one thing I'm not sure about:

```
pinctrl-names = "default";
pinctrl-0 = <&epd_pins>;
```

I've seen properties like that in other's DTs with `gpio` fragments, but not always; sometimes they are, sometimes they're not. If I comment out these two lines, it seems like nothing changes, and my driver still works as it should.

I have two questions:

1. What is the purpose of those `pinctrl` lines? I'm aware of pin controller subsystem, but I'm asking strictly in context of my DT.
2. Why do I need to declare the `gpio` overlay? I set IN or OUT function directly from my driver code anyway and my gpio numbers are defined in `spi` overlay (`dc-gpios`, `reset-gpios`, `busy-gpios`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer you question (assuming you understand the function of the pinctrl line in the device tree in general).

1. When your device is probed by the kernel, if you have those pinctrl lines in your dts then the kernel requests the pinctrl subsystem to configure the pins listed under `brcm,pins` as their respective functions defined under `brcm,function`. The pinctrl state named `default` is requested to be set by the kernel automatically. You may define other states as

   `pinctrl-names = "default", "sleep";`

   `pinctrl-0 = <&spi1_default>;`

   `pinctrl-1 = <&spi1_sleep>;`

   and for other states like sleep or idle you will have to explicitly call them when the driver changes state for power management by calling functions `pinctrl_pm_select_sleep_state` or `pinctrl_pm_select_idle_state` respectively. You can only call these functions if the respective pin states are defined in device tree else you might have to do the configuring manually calling the pinctrl apis.
2. Not necessary in your case, as you are said that you are explicitly setting the pin modes and configuration in device driver, then in that case for your particular case you might not need these lines in your device tree.

Comment: Thanks! One more question to the 1st point: what if two or more pin controllers share the same pins? Which pin controller is the winner? I'd be happy to remove GPIO settings from my driver code, but how can I be sure, that my pin controller is currently in effect?

Comment: @itachi if by "two or more pin controllers" you mean the `pinctrl-x` declaration, then the one that gets configured the last is the winner i.e the one that makes the last call to pin control is the winner.

Comment: Not exactly, I was thinking about a situation, when in DT two different devices with pin controllers have one or more common pins. That should not happen, but what if?

Comment: in that case the device whose probe function is called last is the ones whose setting is applied to the pin. (you can of course over ride it in the driver init code but two devices/drivers expecting same pins simultaneously is not a good idea)

Comment: Your answer and comments are very helpful. Is there a chance you know the location of the code, which parses "pinctrl" entries in DT and uses them to configure those pins? I understand that I'm not obliged to do this in my code.

Comment: you can find it under `drivers/of`. I dont know the exact part of code but it must be under this directory